# How to connect ArcMap 10.0 query layer to a different port?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, postgresql, query-layer

I have an instance where I have a server that has postgres 8.3 and postgres 9.2 on it. I have the 8.3 version on port 5432 and 9.2 on port 5433. I want to connect to the 9.2 instance, here is a screenshot of the setup:

[image]

This however is not working. It comes back as an invalid username and password because it is trying to connect to the 8.3 version, which the username and password does not exist on. However, if I do try one with the username/password of the 8.3 it works. I believe I am missing something with how ArcMap wants to configure the port number in the configuration box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to add a PGPORT to the **Data Source** text box. So the result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: So I am going to add one note for future viewers: this doesn't post well to a ArcServer 10.0 :/. It appears that the server chokes on that port. So if you are trying to publish the layer... Good luck!